# Does a Space with the Finite Closed Topology have Fixed Point Property?

Tags: general-topology

I wanted to know if a space $(X, \tau)$ with $\tau$ the finite-closed topology, have the Fixed Point Property, that is if every continuous mapping $f$ of $(X, \tau)$ into itself has a fixed point.

Comment: If $X$ is finite, then $(X,\tau)$ is discrete, and therefore it doesn't have the fixed point property unless $X=\{x\}$.

Comment: In that topology **every** bijection of $X$ to itself is continuous, and there are always bijections without fixed points unless $|X|=1$.

Comment: What is the "finite-closed topology"? The topology in which all proper closed sets are finite? If so, as @BrianM.Scott says, this is not true. (In fact, I'm pretty sure this is true for *any* topology which you can specify as "the" topology, without specifying the underlying set or any other data...)

Comment: @tomasz: I’m assuming that it’s an alternative name for the cofinite topology; I’m pretty sure that I’ve seen the term used that way.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: If you specify no data, then either the topology is non-unique (hence, it is not "the" topology), or it is necessarily homogeneous (in the sense that the automorphism group acts transitively), so it does not have fpp if $X$ has at least two distinct points.

Comment: @tomasz Derp, not my finest moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topology you have in mind - more commonly called the **cofinite topology** - looks a lot like the discrete topology in a few ways. One of these ways is the following:

> **Every** self-bijection is continuous with respect to the cofinite topology.

The proof is basically immediate: the preimage of a cofinite set under an injective map must be cofinite.

Now if $X$ is any set with more than one element, there is a permutation of $X$ with no fixed points (exercise$^1$), so in fact no space with the cofinite topology which has more than one point has the fixed point property.

---

$^1$Amusingly, this actually requires a small amount of the axiom of choice: it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ (= set theory without choice) that there is a set with more than one element such that every self-bijection of the set has a fixed point. In fact it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there is an infinite set $A$ such that every self-bijection of $A$ fixes all but finitely many points! This is very difficult to prove however (as all $\mathsf{ZF}$-consistency results are), but Cohen's original model of $\mathsf{ZF+\neg AC}$ provides an example. In such a model we do indeed have infinite sets which, when equipped with the cofinite topology, have the fixed point property. But these are extremely pathological models.

Answer (score 0):

The natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ with the cofinite( so that means finite sets are closed) topology does not have the fixed point property, since the $\sigma(n)=n+1$ map does not have fixed points, however takes open sets to open sets.